# Error with all XSLTs when referring DotNetOpenAuth.DLL - Umbraco 4.7.1

Tags: xslt, umbraco, dotnetopenauth

I just referred DotNetOpenAuth.DLL and all XSLTs are showing error..

Removing DotNetOpenAuth makes all work fine!!.. It seems like some kind of bug..

I am on a project deadline and its DotNetOpenAuth is a must to finish it..

Please help.......

---

I just tried the Trace and here is more info --

Unable to load one or more of the types in assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth, Version=3.4.5.10202, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246'. Exceptions were thrown:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Unable to load one or more of the types in assembly 'DotNetOpenAuth, Version=3.4.5.10202, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246'. Exceptions were thrown:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  at umbraco.BusinessLogic.Utils.TypeFinder.FindClassesMarkedWithAttribute(Assembly assembly, Type attribute)
  at umbraco.BusinessLogic.Utils.TypeFinder.FindClassesMarkedWithAttribute(Type attribute)
  at umbraco.macro.GetXsltExtensionsImpl()
  at umbraco.cms.businesslogic.cache.Cache.GetCacheItem[TT](String cacheKey, Object syncLock, CacheItemPriority priority, CacheItemRemovedCallback refreshAction, CacheDependency cacheDependency, TimeSpan timeout, GetCacheItemDelegate`1 getCacheItem)
  at umbraco.macro.GetXsltExtensions()
  at umbraco.macro.AddMacroXsltExtensions()
  at umbraco.macro.GetXsltTransformResult(XmlDocument macroXML, XslCompiledTransform xslt, Dictionary`2 parameters)
  at umbraco.macro.loadMacroXSLT(macro macro, MacroModel model, Hashtable pageElements)

Comment: Your question is far too vague. What errors are you seeing? Can you provide some simple code that reproduces the error?

Comment: Its just the "ERROR PARSING XSLT FILE: \XSLT\NAVIGATION.XSLT" error.. Just refer DotNetOpenAuth and all XSLTs are failing!!

Answer (score 2):

I got the fix http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/22533-Upgrade-to-470-Recaptcha-missing-assembly-reference

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: I needed to use `newVersion="3.0.0.0"` to make it work in my case.